# Open Word document at specific bookmark

Tags: hyperlink, word

I have a Word document on SharePoint shared with everyone. I would like to embed the link to this document on different pages on my website.

Every page's link should be open the document at specific bookmark (not page!). Is it possible somehow?

Comment: what this means **at specific bookmark (not page!).**

Comment: I'm able to open the document at specific page number, but I have to open it at specific bookmark, due everybody can edit the file.

Comment: which SharePoint you are using online or some server !

Comment: @cjs How can I know what we are using? This is a closed version of SharePoint created for my company and we can access it internally only.